# Google maps display customer data in balloons without disclosing it (publicly or to Google)?

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to create a map of customer locations using Google maps.

It would be very convenient to display customer information in the balloons that pop up when you click a marker. However, some of that data should not be public, and the company would rather not disclose it to Google either.

I have access to (and can set up a server if need be) that runs something server side to generate .kml, Javascript, or serve a web page (including the js in that).

I've thought of a few ways to go about this. First is embedding html in .kml and having the contents of the balloon replaced by JavaScript making an asynchronous request to a private url/server. Unfortunately, it looks like JavaScript is stripped out if you are loading a .kml file by just putting the URL of the .kml file in the search box of google maps. I also found that it seems that iframes are also stripped out.  One thing I do not know is if I set up a xhtml page that uses the Google maps API if that would let me load data from a private server directly to the browser without that data being loaded through Google.

One option that appears it will work is just putting a link in the .kml html for the balloon and having that link go somewhere. But that makes a whole extra step to see what the marker is, and diminishes the value of the whole thing in the first place.

So, is there a way to do what I'm attempting to do (load private data into the placemark bubbles directly to the user's browser instead of through Google)? If so, which option is the most maintainable/clean?

Comment: I suspect that if you use client-side javascript to manually create each infobox and add it to the map, Google doesn't find out about it. But I'm not certain that the data isn't sent. If you use this approach, your server-side would render a html/js page, and also provide an array of locations/notes; then the client JS would iterate over the array and add them to the map.

Comment: Google's API allows you to create and manipulate a map on your own site. Google doesn't know what data you are placing on that map.

Comment: Thanks Adam and @Plato . I was able to get a version of this working to some extent today, though I an still having some trouble, but that is because I'm not good at javascript yet. Stuff for another question I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

With Google's map API, you can write an (x)html page that loads a google map using javascript.

You can then have that javascript load data from a server directly to the browser (in something like JSON or XML) where the javascript can parse it and then add each point to the map. That way, the data does not route through Google's servers.